# No rule to make target '.kernel_signing_key.pem', needed by 'certs/signing_key.x509'

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I ran `make O=/home/stephen/build/kernel V=1 all` according to the document, the working directory is `/home/stephen/linux-5.17` then it threw an error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '.kernel_signing_key.pem', needed by 'certs/signing_key.x509'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [/home/stephen/linux-5.17/Makefile:1831: certs] Error 2
```

And I have totally no idea about it.
Could anyone tell me how to deal with this?

Comment: Probably this could help, I don't know for sure https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294116